# How to write a google script for google calendar?

Tags: javascript, calendar

I want to make this Google script that takes only current days events from Google Calendar and log them out.

This script works, but it logs out all the upcoming events and I only need current day events.

```
function listUpcomingEvents() {
  var calendarId = 'primary';
  var optionalArgs = {
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    showDeleted: false,
    singleEvents: true,
    maxResults: 10,
    orderBy: 'startTime'
  };

  var response = Calendar.Events.list(calendarId, optionalArgs);
  var events = response.items;
  if (events.length > 0) {
    for (i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
      var event = events[i];
      var when = event.start.dateTime;
      if (!when) {
        when = event.start.date;
      }
      Logger.log('%s (%s)', event.summary, when);
    }
  } else {
    Logger.log('No upcoming events found.');
  }
}
```

Also I need to make this script publishable as a web app... Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For just the current day events you can use timeMin and timeMax parameters. You can read the api from the link.

for those who dont want to open the link here is the parameters explanation:

timeMax:    datetime    Upper bound (exclusive) for an event's start time to filter by. Optional. The default is not to filter by start time. Must be an RFC3339 timestamp with mandatory time zone offset, e.g., 2011-06-03T10:00:00-07:00, 2011-06-03T10:00:00Z. Milliseconds may be provided but will be ignored.

timeMin:    datetime    Lower bound (inclusive) for an event's end time to filter by. Optional. The default is not to filter by end time. Must be an RFC3339 timestamp with mandatory time zone offset, e.g., 2011-06-03T10:00:00-07:00, 2011-06-03T10:00:00Z. Milliseconds may be provided but will be ignored.

[google calender api link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)